# Is 'action this matter' a correct phrase?

Tags: grammaticality, parts-of-speech, business-language

Is 'action this matter' a correct phrase? Is it correct to say "Pls check with Mr. X to ascertain whether his team or we should action this matter."

Comment: It's cringe-inducing  corporate speak, but given that it's also clear and comprehensible, yes, it's valid (whether you want to be known as a person who encourages corporate-speak is a different question....).

Comment: Bureaucratese -- esp., in India, and maybe some others with a colonial hangover. :)

Comment: So, yes, it works.

Answer (score 0):

**[action](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/action)** (scroll down to see the entries)
*vb (tr)*

> **20**. to put into effect; take action concerning: *matters decided at the meeting cannot be actioned until the following week.*
>
> **Verb 1. action** - … expedite - process fast and efficiently; "I will try to expedite the matter"